# writing a simple help menu with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, menu, helper

Any advice on how to create a simple help menu with Qt? I could not really find anything interesting in the examples.

What I have in mind is nothing too fancy like a whole window that looks like a web browser with a search engine, I just want to write few paragraphs, but maybe starting with links to each paragraph at the top, really like a basic web FAQ.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whats wrong with http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.8-snapshot/qthelp.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to implement it yourself, there are a number of ways.

That might be an overkill, but you can make your help as a number of local HTML pages which have links to each other, and use `QWebView` to show them to the user.

A simpler method would be to use a list or articles with search:

- `QListWidget` to hold the names of the articles. When the user clicks one, you will open it.
- `QLineEdit` with a `QCompleter` attached to search through this list (by article name, nothing too complicated).
- `QTextBrowser` to display the article. Remember that `QTextBrowser` can render HTML, so you can make the articles look fancy.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I still haven't thought hard enough about what I want to do, but I'll probably follow your second suggestion, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Qt Help Framework](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-maemo/qthelp-framework.html). If you aren't searching for a complex help system you may use a [QTextEdit](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtextedit.html) with HTML or you can give a link to an online documentation in your program's menus.